# How to get largest value along with text/name from a dimensional array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a dimensional 'dataArray' as given below.

```
dataArray = [ {name:"Apples", score: 3.5}, {name:"Oranges", score: 3.7}, {name:"Grapes", score: 4.1} ];
```

Would like to get the highest score from the dataArray along with the name ?

```
function playerArray() {

  dataArray = [{
    name: "Apples",
    score: 3.5
  }, {
    name: "Oranges",
    score: 3.7
  }, {
    name: "Grapes",
    score: 4.1
  }];

  for (i = 0; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
    var nameArray = dataArray[0].name;
    var scoreArray = dataArray[0].score;

    var largest = Math.max.apply(Math, scoreArray);

    alert(largest[0].score);
  }
}
```

On executing the 'playerArray()' it throws following error:
test.html:24 Uncaught TypeError: CreateListFromArrayLike called on non-object
    at playerArray

Comment: You don't want to include the *Math.max* part in the loop, put it after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nice and simple way:

```
dataArray = [ {name:"Apples", score: 3.5}, {name:"Oranges", score: 3.7}, {name:"Grapes", score: 4.1} ];

var maxScore = {name:'',score:0};

for(var i = 0; i< dataArray.length; i++){
  var currElem = dataArray[i];
  var currScore = currElem.score;

  //keep track of highest score so far
  if(maxScore.score < currScore){
     maxScore.name = currElem.name;
     maxScore.score = currElem.score;
  }

}

console.log(maxScore)
```

[Live example here](http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/wgePEP)

If you want you can also be less verbose by doing:

```
 if(maxScore.score < currScore){
     maxScore = currElem;
  }
```

If you want to be a little more elegant and avoid the loop plus a few variables, then use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```
var maxScore = {name:'',score:0};

dataArray.map(function(elem) {
  if (maxScore.score < elem.score) {
    maxScore = elem
  }
});
```

[Live example of map approach here](http://codepen.io/pabs123/pen/qRjVQd)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
let dataArray = [ {name:"Apples", score: 3.5}, {name:"Oranges", score: 3.7}, {name:"Grapes", score: 4.1} ];

let max = dataArray.reduce((acc,elem) => { return elem.score > acc.score ? elem : acc }, {name: "", score: -1});

console.log(max);
```

Comment: Perhaps initialise score with `-Infinity` just to be sure. If there will always be at least one member in *dataArray*, no initial value for the accumulator is required. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use an index (`maxIndex`) to search with like this:

```js
dataArray = [{
  name: "Apples",
  score: 3.5
}, {
  name: "Oranges",
  score: 3.7
}, {
  name: "Grapes",
  score: 4.1
}];

var maxIndex = 0;
for (i = 1; i < dataArray.length; i++) {
  if(dataArray[maxIndex].score < dataArray[i].score)
    maxIndex = i;
}

var maxObj = dataArray[maxIndex];

console.log(maxObj);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a terribly straightforward job with a simple reduce. I guess this use of `.reduce()` is as fundamental as it is the summing array elements example we see everywhere.

```
arraySum = arr.reduce((p,c) => p+c)
```

Now as per this one;

```js
var data = [ {name:"Apples", score: 3.5}, {name:"Oranges", score: 3.7}, {name:"Grapes", score: 4.1} ],
 dataMax = data.reduce((p,c) => p.score > c.score ? p : c);
console.log(dataMax);
```